# Dynamically adding checkboxes to multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I have been stuck on this problem for hours and I am going mad ! I need a dropdown of checkboxes - which I populate dynamically into a select tag. I also need to append each multiselect dropdown that I deep-clone with jquery to a number of `<div>` elements. However, every time I do this the cloned element is rendered as a list of multiselectable items (and not as a dropdown and loses all its styling). This is the multiselect container that I would like to add my checkboxes to:

```
<select class="multiselect1" multiple="multiple">


</select>
```

I finally initialize each cloned dropdown by calling .multiselect(); The library I am using for this is: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

```
        $('.multiselect1').multiselect();
        var filterClone = $('.multiselect1').clone(true);
        //filterClone.multiselect();
        $('body').append(filterClone[0]);
```

When the above lines execute, the select element is indeed present in the body but is invisible. When I remove the style attribute the element becomes visible but is rendered as a list of multiselectable items (which is expected). But why is the cloned multiselectable dropdown not displayed at all in the first place ?

Any suggestions that could lead me to a solution (or the solutions itself!) using javascript or jquery would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well to make this work you need JQuery. Did you include JQuery? If you didn't you can use this: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` Did you upload all the files to your server?

Try this code on your website. Does it work?

HTML:

```
<select id="SOExample" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Love it!">Love it!</option>
    <option value="Hate it!">Hate it!</option>
    <option value="I don't know...">I don't know...</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#SOExample').multiselect();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @ Martijn Melchers, could you please have a look at the question again, I have added more details. The cloned dropdown basically does not render at all. When I try removing the style attribute the  element displays as a list of multiselectable items.

Comment: Did you include the css @user1841702?

Comment: @ Martijn Melchers, Yes I have included all the prerequisite files. I am certain of this because when I test the example it runs just fine.

Comment: Why do you have the `class` element in your select? @user1841702 If you want to select it with javascript you have to have `id`